# Python and data analysis how can we transform a json array into rows having json properties as columns titles?

Tags: python, json

I need to create a recommendation system for a small company using its 500 first orders.

I received a `.json` file having the following structure:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "seller_id": 1,
            "customer_id": 4,
            "order_status_id": 6,
            "product_id": 2591,
            "quantity": 4
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "seller_id": 1,
            "customer_id": 4,
            "order_status_id": 6,
            "product_id": 2592,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "seller_id": 19,
            "customer_id": 5,
            "order_status_id": 6,
            "product_id": 1025,
            "quantity": 3
        },

        ...
```

I am new to machine learning and data analysis using python. What I need is group each `order_id` as a line a dataframe, where it contains:

```
order id 1    product 1    product 2    product 3

order id 2    product 3    product 4    product 6   product 125
```

This is for the `apriori` algorithms.

But for the data analysis, how can split each row into a line with columns in a series or data frame.

I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_json('orders.json')
```

And I tried this:

```
data = pd.read_json('orders.json')['data']
```

But what I've got is the following:

[image: Image 1]